# Can Greek letters be added to Sphinx documents as glossary terms?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, glossary

I want to add variables that are defined as Greek letters to my glossary in a sphinx document. For example:

```
.. glossary::

    :math:`{\alpha}`
        Definition for alpha
```

The goal is to have these variables appear in the document's index. Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Syntax wasn't my concern, but I updated the example to eliminate confusion. I'd like to be able to define glossary terms that are Greek letters.

Comment: It would help if you explained what the actual problem is.

Comment: Sure. In the example above, a Greek letter will be added to the document with a definition. However, the Greek letter (in this case alpha) will not appear in the glossary as a term.

Comment: That is not what I see. The alpha character is there as a term in the glossary in the output. But with your example, Sphinx (1.4.9) emits this warning "WARNING: invalid single index entry ''" (which is related to the fact that glossary terms are added to the index as well).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The indexing functionality is what I want to achieve, is that possible with Greek letters?

Comment: So you get the same warning then?

Comment: Nope. I'm using Sphinx 1.4.9 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glossary terms are automatically added to the index. But that does not work for the glossary entry in the question. Sphinx emits this warning: `WARNING: invalid single index entry ''` (at least it does for me). This feels like a bug.

Here are two workarounds:

1. Use a substitution

   ```
   |alpha|
      Description of alpha

   .. |alpha| replace:: :math:`{\alpha}`
   ```

   The drawback is that it will say "alpha" in the index instead of "α".
2. Use the actual alpha letter

   ```
   α
      Description of alpha
   ```

   Here α will be an entry in the index under the heading "Symbols".

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm going to use the second option because it will use the character in the index.